# Take one massive table and break it into smaller & easier to maintain tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have this big database table that tracks (currently in production), a persons medical certification by: Date expires (exp), the company, if we have it on file and the location of a digital copy. We track in many (growing) categories such as CPR, CPR child, AED, Lifeguarding etc...

How do I make this easier to manage and how can I migrate existing data over? I'm coldfusion web app running SQL server 2008.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[mod_StudentCertifications](
    [certificationID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [profileID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [cprAdultExp] [datetime] NULL,
    [cprAdultcompany] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [cprAdultImage] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
    [cprAdultOnFile] [bit] NULL,
    [cprInfantChildExp] [datetime] NULL,
    [cprInfantChildcompany] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [cprInfantChildImage] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
    [cprInfantChildOnFile] [bit] NULL,
    [cprFPRExp] [datetime] NULL,
    [cprFPRcompany] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [cprFPRImage] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
    [cprFPROnFile] [bit] NULL,
    [aedExp] [datetime] NULL,
    [aedcompany] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [aedImage] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
    [aedOnFile] [bit] NULL,
    [firstAidExp] [datetime] NULL,
    [firstAidcompany] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [firstAidImage] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
    [firstAidOnFile] [bit] NULL,
    [emtExp] [datetime] NULL,
    [emtcompany] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [emtImage] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
    [emtOnFile] [bit] NULL,
    [waterSafetyInstructionExp] [datetime] NULL,
    [waterSafetyInstructioncompany] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [waterSafetyInstructionImage] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
    [waterSafetyInstructionOnFile] [bit] NULL,
    [bloodPathogensExp] [datetime] NULL,
    [bloodPathogenscompany] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [bloodPathogensImage] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
    [bloodPathogensOnFile] [bit] NULL,
    [oxygenAdminExp] [datetime] NULL,
    [oxygenAdmincompany] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [oxygenAdminImage] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
    [oxygenAdminOnFile] [bit] NULL,
    [lifegaurdingExp] [datetime] NULL,
    [lifegaurdingcompany] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [lifegaurdingImage] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
    [lifegaurdingOnFile] [bit] NULL,
    [wildernessResponderExp] [datetime] NULL,
    [wildernessResponderCompany] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [wildernessResponderImage] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
    [wildernessResponderOnFile] [bit] NULL,
    [certNotes] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
    [isActive] [bit] NULL,
    [certClassRegistered] [bit] NULL,
    [lifeguardInstrcutorExp] [datetime] NULL,
    [lifeguardInstrcutorCompany] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [lifeguardInstrcutorImage] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
    [lifeguardInstrcutorOnFile] [bit] NULL
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice how all of your certifications have the same repeating columns of information: Expiration, Company, Image, OnFile? That's a big clue that you're in need of further normalization of your design.

In a perfect world (one where you're able to make schema changes), I'd create a generic student/certification table, with those common elements as columns, a foreign key to another table that enumerates the certificates (Water Safety, Wilderness, etc.) and another foreign key linking the students to those certifications. Something like:

[image]

Comment: Is there an easy way to move the data?

Comment: That depends on what you expect to happen while the data is being moved. It is trivial to generate the scripts once the new tables are built, but can the application be offline so that users don't impact the change while the data is moving?

Comment: It can be offline to move data.

Comment: @Snow_Mac: Then as Aaron indicated, the scripts to move the data should be trivial. The bigger pain will be refactoring existing code to use the new schema design.